# No encuentra los datos en un diccionario

Tags: python, busqueda

Asi como esta me encuentra la cédula y me muestra todos los datos, pero cuando descomento todo no me encuentra los datos, ¿cómo puedo hacer que funcione?

```python
def calculo():
                try:
                    cedula = input("Por favor digite la cedula del cliente para realizar el calculo de su IMC: ")
                    # Buscar en las listas
                    # for x in diccionario.keys():
                    if cedula in diccionario:
                        print(diccionario[cedula])
                        # datos_cliente = diccionario[cedula]
                        # edadEcon = datos_cliente["Edad"]
                        # pesoC= datos_cliente["Peso"]
                        # alturaC=datos_cliente["Altura"]
                        # imc = (pesoC / (alturaC * alturaC)) * 10000 
                        # # Categoría niños
                        # if 5 <= edadEcon <= 12:
                        #         if imc < 11.80:
                        #             resultado = "Desnutricion severa"
                        #         elif 11.80 <= imc < 14.30:
                        #             resultado = "Desnutricion moderada"
                        #         elif 14.30 <= imc < 21.30:
                        #             resultado = "Normal"
                        #         elif 17.00 <= imc <= 25.60:
                        #             resultado = "Sobrepeso"
                        #         else:
                        #             resultado = "Obesidad"
                                
                        #         datos_cliente["IMC"]= imc
                        #         datos_cliente["Resultado"]= resultado
                        #         print(datos_cliente)
                        #         print("Guardado exitosamente")

                        #     # Categoría jóvenes
                        # #categoria jovenes
                        # elif 13 <= edadEcon < 18:
                        #         if imc < 13.20:
                        #             resultado = "Desnutricion severa"
                        #         elif 13.20 <= imc < 16.30:
                        #             resultado = "Desnutricion moderada"
                        #         elif 16.30 <= imc < 24.80:
                        #             resultado = "Normal"
                        #         elif 24.80 <= imc <= 28.50:
                        #             resultado = "Sobrepeso"
                        #         else:
                        #             resultado = "Obesidad"

                        #         datos_cliente["IMC"]= imc
                        #         datos_cliente["Resultado"]= resultado
                        #         print(datos_cliente)
                        #         print("Guardado exitosamente")

                            
                        #     #adultos
                        # #categoria adultos 
                        # elif edadEcon<= 18:
                        #     if imc < 16.00:
                        #         resultado = "Desnutricion severa"
                        #     elif 16.00 <= imc < 18.50:
                        #         resultado = "Desnutricion moderada"
                        #     elif 18.00 <= imc < 24.00:
                        #         resultado = "Normal"
                        #     elif 24.00 <= imc <= 34.00:
                        #         resultado = "Sobrepeso"
                        #     else:
                        #             resultado = "Obesidad"

                        #     datos_cliente["IMC"]= imc
                        #     datos_cliente["Resultado"]= resultado
                        #     print(datos_cliente)
                        #     print("Guardado exitosamente")

                    else:
                        print("La cedula no se encuentra registrada")
                    return

                except ValueError as e:
                    print(f"Error: {e}")
```

Comment: Hola Caroro19, ¿cual es la salida cuando lo descomentas? ¿Se ejecuta el `elif` "La cédula no se encuentra"? ¿Se ejecuta el `exept`? ¿Con que excepción? A simple vista lo que veo es un typo en el condicional para adultos, tienes `elif edadEcon<= 18:` y debería ser `elif edadEcon >= 18:`.